# how to make ejabberd chat room to accept invitations without invitee being online

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, multiuserchat

how to make the invited users to join MUC chatroom without them being online. Like how whatsapp handles the user invitations. Without the invitee accepting the invitation the users can start messaging them.